# From known power series deduce the power series expansion of $ln(5-x)$ and infer the general term and radius of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

From known power series deduce the power series expansion of $ln(5-x)$ and infer the general term and radius of convergence.

Now I said:

$ln(5-x)=ln(5(1-\frac{x}{5})=ln(5)+ln(1-\frac{x}{5})=ln(5)-\frac{x}{5}-\frac{(\frac{x}{5})^2}{2}-\frac{(\frac{x}{5})^3}{3}- ...-\frac{(\frac{x}{5})^{n+2}}{n+2}$

Where n is an integer greater than 0.

Now what is then the general term of this series?

Also I saw that for the series: $ln(1+x)$ the radius of convergence is $-1<x<=1$

So applying the same principle to the aforementioned series that should mean that the radius of convergence is:

$-1<\frac{-x}{5}<=1$ which the same as $5>x>=-5$. However this is wrong since the series actually converges only for $5>x>-5$.

What did I do wrong?

Kind Regards and thank you very much for your help!

(side note: the use of taylor polynomial is not permitted in the solution)

Comment: Also, it is incorrect in that you keep subtracting the same term, every other term, for some reason.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series

Comment: Oh ye that was my mistake I fixed that.

Comment: Still does not alternate signs. Should start with a + sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series for $\ln(1 - x)$:

$$x-\frac{(x)^2}{2}+\frac{(x)^3}{3} + \ldots + -\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x)^n}{n}$$

So you should put:

$$\ln(5-x) = \ln(5) + \frac{x}{5}-\frac{(\frac{x}{5})^2}{2}+\frac{(\frac{x}{5})^3}{3} + \ldots + -\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(\frac{x}{5})^n}{n}$$
The general term is the last one above with $n$ in it.